# How to turn off stepping through classes that are not mine in Java/VSCode

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am stepping through a program I made. When I am debugging however, whenever i step through, my VSCode pops open classes like `ArrayList.class` or `Someabstractclass.class` and I only want to step through my code and to throw uncaught exceptions similar to C# and visual studio. Is this possible?

Comment: why dont you use step over instead? If you use stepin , it will take you in the implementation.

Comment: Ahhh.. i thought Step Over literally skipped a line of code.. I guess thats a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Look at the "skipFiles" attribute for your launch config.  See, e.g., https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_just-my-code-improvements